# How do I know whether an observable was changed by an input binding with Knockout.js?

Tags: knockout.js

I want to implement a feature to automatically populate a field based on the value of two other fields but allow the user to override the calculated suggested value. For example:

Input 1: _________

Input 2: _________

Input 3: Input 1 / Input 2 by default

I want to update Input 3 whenever Input 1 or 2 changes but I don't want to change Input 3 if the user has explicitly changed its value. Now, how can I be notified that Input 3 has been changed due to the user typing (or dragging or pasting) and not due to the code updating it when Input 1 and 2 change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution is to use [writable computed observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html)

[Link to working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/rcc07309/2/)

HTML:

```
Value 1: <input type="number" data-bind='value: value1' />
<br/>
Value 2: <input type="number" data-bind='value: value2' />
<br/>
Value 3: <input type="number" data-bind='value: value3Computed' />
<br/>
```

JavaScript:

```
function MyViewModel() {
    this.value1 = ko.observable(1);
    this.value2 = ko.observable(2);
    this.value3 = ko.observable(null);

    this.value3Computed = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return this.value3() || this.value1() / this.value2();
        },
        write: function (value) {
            this.value3(value);
        },
        owner: this
    });
}
var vm = new MyViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Comment: I was just about to write that as I was reading about Writable Computed Observables and then I noticed your response, but thanks for pointing that out :)